# Find and delete folder + files within

Tags: find, delete

I got a directory structure like this:

```
/backups/
/backups/db/
/backups/db/01.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
/backups/db/02.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
/backups/db/03.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
/backups/db/04.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
```

Now Im running this command:

```
find /backups/db/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +2 -delete && rsync ...
```

When I execute this command directly in the shell, it works and the result is:

```
/backups/
/backups/db/
/backups/db/03.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
/backups/db/04.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
```

If I run this command by a cronjob, the directories wont be deleted and the result is:

```
/backups/
/backups/db/
/backups/db/01.01.2020/
/backups/db/02.01.2020/
/backups/db/03.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
/backups/db/04.01.2020/domain_a.sql.gz, domain_b.sql.gz, domain_c.sql.gz
```

This happens cause `find` first delete the files within these (2) folders and this action change the date of these folders, so that they dont match anymore the `-mtime +2`.

Is there any solution? I mean I could go with something like this, but I usually dont like to work with rm if its not necessary.

```
find /backups/db/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +6 -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this in two steps, and that you only delete *files* in the first step:

```
find /backups/db -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 -delete
```

Then delete empty directories:

```
find /backups/db -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

This way you don't compare timestamps on directories at all.

You could possibly combine the two operations into

```
find /backups/db -mindepth 1 \
    \( \( -type f -mtime +2 \) -o \
       \( -type d -empty    \) \) -delete
```

... but you may want to check without `-delete` that it does the correct thing first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I go with `find /backups/db -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 -delete && find /backups/db -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete`. But I will also checkout the combined version. :)